# Implementing the (typed) K combinator in C++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, functor, higher-order-functions

I am trying to implement the K combinator from the [SK combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description) in C++. The K combinator is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that basically takes some value `x`, and returns something which *in turn* takes a value `y` and returns `x` from it. In other words,

```
K(x)(y) == x
```

or step-by-step:

```
intermediate = K(x)
intermediate(y) == x
```

The ability to treat `K(x)` as a thing-in-itself, independent of `y`, is essential. Furthermore, it should not be necessary to specify the type of `y` when simply creating `K(x)` without calling it on `y`. The type of `y` can be specified once `K(x)(y)` is being evaluated somewhere in the code.

I am trying to fix the code I wrote which attempts to implement the K combinator:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A>
template<class B>
auto K = [](A x) {
    return [=](B y) {
        return x;
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    auto Kx = K<int>(3);
    auto Kxy = Kx<float>(4.5);
    std::cout << Kxy << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs `error: extraneous template parameter list in template specialization or out-of-line template definition`. I have tried adjusting the template parameters and moving them around to no avail. Does anyone know how I could fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambdas cannot be templates. You can do this though:

```
#include <iostream>

auto K = [](auto x) {
    return [=](auto y) {
        return x;
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    auto Kx = K(3);
    auto Kxy = Kx(4.5);
    std::cout << Kxy << std::endl;
}
```

These are called generic lambdas (exist since C++14), and are basically what you want. Their `operator()` is template for each `auto` parameter.

Comment: You can have templated variables in C++14. You might also want to add a note that generic lambdas are part of C++14 as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg which is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite possible even of you don't have C++14 – just remember that lambdas are merely a shortcut notation for functor objects. We can therefore create an object representing the intermediate value:

```
template<class A>
class Intermediate {
  A m_a;
public:
  explicit Intermediate(const A& a)
  : m_a(a)
  {}

  template<class B>
  A operator()(const B&) const
  { return m_a; }
};

template<class A>
Intermediate<A> K(const A& a)
{ return Intermediate<A>(a); }
```

The separate `K` function is necessary for template argument deduction so that we can write `K(x)(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can "solve" it by the following change:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto K = [](A x) {
    return [=](B y) {
        return x;
    };
};
```

However, you then need to change the calls as well:

```
auto Kx = K<int, float>(3);
auto Kxy = Kx(4.5);
```

---

As an explaining note, while lambdas themselves can't be templated, but from C++14 variables can, and what I'm doing is declaring `K` as a templated variable, it just so happens that the variable is declared as a lambda object.

Comment: Is that syntax real?   http://ideone.com/gjWyf5  You should look at Yuri's answer.

Comment: @xaxxon Yuri's answer is better, which is why I voted for it, but this works well in C++14 using an old clang compiler. Might be a bug in clang though, or it might be a bug in GCC on ideone, I don't know.