# Implementing the primitive recursive combinator in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, metaprogramming, higher-order-functions

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403540/implementing-the-typed-k-combinator-in-c/35403766#35403766) regarding the implementation of the [K combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description), I am trying to implement the so-called [R combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_functional) which represents [primitive recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition):

```
R a b zero = a
R a b (successor c) = b c (R a b c)
```

where `successor` is the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition). The type signature of R is

```
A → ((ℕ → (A → A)) → (ℕ → A))
```

I attempted to implement it using the following code:

```
auto R = [](auto a) {
    return [=](auto b) {
        return [=](auto c) {
            if (c == zero) return a;
            else return b(c)(R(a)(b)(c - 1));
        };
    };
};
```

using [generic lambdas](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas) (from C++14). Unfortunately, my compiler yields the following error:

```
error: variable 'R' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its own initializer
                    else return b(c)(R(a)(b)(c - 1));
                                     ^
```

The problem seems to be that the lambda cannot reference itself within its own body. Is there a clean/concise way to solve this problem, while retaining the `auto` template parameters?

More information about the primitive recursive functionals are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_functional).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn `R` into a named function or functor, which may be referenced in this way. This is a little more awkward than lambdas but does solve the problem.

Another typical strategy is to Y combine the lambda so that you can gain access to it as a parameter.

Comment: How could I turn `R` into a named function or functor while retaining the generic aspect (i.e. not having to specify the types it will take beforehand)?